# Why was a resistor and capacitor used in this IR receiver circuit

Tags: pic, infrared

[image: IR receiver circuit with output to PIC18F1220]

The circuit shows an IR receiver whose output pin is interfaced with a PIC. Can you explain why a resistor and capacitor were used and why those values were picked.

Answer (score 7):

As the datasheet clearly says, the TSOP output is open collector.  This means it needs a passive pullup to go high.

However, the circuit you show is messed up in several ways.  Assuming whatever you find on the internet to be good coupled with not reading the datasheet leads to trouble.  Specifically, problems with this circuit are:

100 Ω is a really low value for the pullup.  The TSOP would have to sink 50 mA to bring that low.  That's so much that I would not assume the TSOP can do that unless the datasheet explicitly says so.  In any case, that much current is totally unnecessary.  10 kΩ would be a much better pullup value.

100µF on the output line is excessive, and totally unnecessary.  The circuitry inside the TSOP already produces a clear digital output that does not bounce.  There is no point in filtering that output further.  Perhaps that cap was intended to be between power and ground, but that's not what the schematic shows.

There is no decoupling cap.  Again, read the TSOP datahseet.  If I remember right, this even specifies a minimum decoupling capacitance.  C1 may have been intended to be between power and ground, which would make a lot more sense than where it is shown.  Even if so, a 1 to 10 µF ceramic would be more approriate than a 100 µF electrolytic.

All in all, this circuit is a mess.  Delete it, don't trust anything else you find on that website, and move on.

Answer (score 7):

The author of that diagram swapped the connections for output and power. Check the datasheet of the TSOP17 series and you will see that it has 3 connections, not 4, and the missing one is the one that is unconnected in your diagram.

[image]

The top connection (1) is the output (NOT +5V as in your diagram). It is open collector, but is has an internal 100k pull-up, so in most cases you won't need an external pull-up.

[image]

Connection 3 is the +5V. The datasheet recommends to decouple it with a 330R / 4u7 filter. Your diagram shows 100R / 100u, which IME is OK too. Needless to say, this pin is NOT the output.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, This datasheet recommends 100 ohms and 4.7uF to filter Vs, and shows the internal pullup as 80K. http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Vishay%20IR%20PDFs/TSOP%2017...pdf

Comment: I took the pictures from a slightly older version of the datasheet (rev A5, yours is rev 10).